# uitextview spelling suggestion off?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

Please help me turning the spelling suggestion in the uitextview when the user inputs some text. can this feature be turned off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, in Interface builder you can turn off autocorrect, or do so in code by changing the autocorrect property.

Comment: txtSearch.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

It worked well, thanks a lot for your kindness Lucius.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this from storyboard. [image: TextViewInStoryboard]

Select the text view in the storyboard and set Correction to Off.